# Dropdownlist Autopostback

Tags: c#, ajax, webforms, drop-down-menu

I have a jquery pop up box that has multiple dropdowns on it and I need to have the final drop down be disabled until everything else is selected.  I come from an MVC world so I planned on using an ajax call to get my filtered data for the final dropdown, but I am curious if there is anyway I can do this with one of the dropdownlists provided events that would not require a postback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript/jquery. Here's an example with three ASP.NET Dropdownlists, the third being the one that will only be enabled if the other two both have a value other than 0:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onchange="HandleStuff()"><asp:ListItem Value="0" /><asp:ListItem Value="1" /><asp:ListItem Value="2" /></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" onchange="HandleStuff()"><asp:ListItem Value="0" /><asp:ListItem Value="1" /><asp:ListItem Value="2" /></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListFinal" runat="server" disabled="disabled"><asp:ListItem Value="0" /><asp:ListItem Value="1" /><asp:ListItem Value="2" /></asp:DropDownList>
```

onchange() calls a method that uses jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HandleStuff() {
        $('#DropDownListFinal').attr('disabled', ($('#DropDownList1').val() == 0 && $('#DropDownList2').val() == 0));
    }
</script>
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: That is the easier part of it.  The second part is getting the data for the FINAL dropdown list that will come from the DB based on the users other selections

Comment: Sorry, didn't read careful enough. However, you'll find lots of examples for a jquery/Ajax script on Google, like http://codeasp.net/blogs/vinay_jss/microsoft-net/715/how-to-populate-dropdownlist-through-jquery